# importing iOS 8 framework that has some iOS 9+ compatible logic

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I have a framework target that is set to deploy on iOS 8. There is one extension in said framework, like so, which is wrapped in an iOS 9 check.

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
extension NSLayoutAnchor {

    open func constrainEqual(_ anchor: NSLayoutAnchor, constant: CGFloat = 0) {
        constraint(equalTo: anchor, constant: constant).isActive = true
    }

}
```

When I import this framework into an App target that has Swift code only and is set to deploy to iOS 8, I get the following error from the imported swift's framework objective-c header file.

:0: error: could not build Objective-C module '' expected a type.

The swift framework's objective-c header file has an error at 'AchorType' in the following line, which is weirdly encapsulated in /* */ for some reason:

```
@interface NSLayoutAnchor (SWIFT_EXTENSION(<module name>))
- (void)constrainEqual:(NSLayoutAnchor</* AnchorType */> * _Nonnull)anchor constant:(CGFloat)constant;
@end
```

It seems like a bug in swift where the automatically generated objective-c header file (for the swift framework) gets it wrong, for this particular type. The problem is solved if I remove the extension.

Am I wrapping it incorrectly ?

Comment: Raised a ticket: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3480

Answer (score 1):

This is currently an issue with swift and objc. Extending objc generics in swift then bridging back into objc is not allowed. Even adding a @nonobjc doesn't fix the issue. Take a look at the bug filed here: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2708 for more info.

A potential fix is to make an extension on each concrete type of NSLayoutAnchor. The concrete types are NSLayoutXAxisAnchor, NSLayoutYAxisAnchor and NSLayoutDimension.

```
extension NSLayoutDimension {
    open func constrainEqual(_ anchor: NSLayoutDimension, constant: CGFloat = 0)
}

extension NSLayoutXAxisAnchor {
    open func constrainEqual(_ anchor: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor, constant: CGFloat = 0)
}

extension NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
    open func constrainEqual(_ anchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor, constant: CGFloat = 0)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I raised this issue and it has recently been resolved. https://bugs.swift.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SR-3480